# Fortran: Read one value at a time from a line

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am using FORTRAN to read in data from an ASCII text file. The file contains multiple data values per line but the number of values per line is not constant.

```
101.5 201.6 21.4 2145.5
45.6 21.2
478.5
...
```

Normally after a read statement, Fortran would go to the next line. What I want to be able to do is read one data value at a time. If it hits the end of the line, it should just continue reading on the next line. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314216/reading-data-file-in-fortran-with-known-number-of-lines-but-unknown-number-of-ent/7315185#7315185 See answer by M.S.B.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by IRO-bot in their comment to your question, the answer has already been given by M.S.B. Below I have merely provided some code illustrating that answer (as M.S.B.'s post contained none):

```
program test

   character(len=40) :: line
   integer           :: success, i, indx, prev, beginning
   real              :: value

   open(1,file='test.txt')

   do  
      read(1,'(A)',iostat=success) line
      if (success.ne.0) exit

      prev      = 1 
      beginning = 1 

      do i=1,len(line)

         ! is the current character one out of the desired set? (if you
         ! have got negative numbers as well, don't forget to add a '-')
         indx = index('0123456789.', line(i:i))

         ! store value when you have reached a blank (or any other 
         ! non-real number character)
         if (indx.eq.0 .and. prev.gt.0) then
            read(line(beginning:i-1), *) value
            print *, value
         else if (indx.gt.0 .and. prev.eq.0) then
            beginning = i 
         end if

         prev = indx
      end do
   end do

   close(1)

end program test
```

When running this program using the sample lines you provided the output is

```
101.5000    
201.6000    
21.40000    
2145.500    
45.60000    
21.20000    
478.5000
```

I hope you will find this helpful.