# Reading an unknown size array from input file

Tags: fortran

I want to read matrix `A` of dimension(n,n) from a input file, `n` is a variable and n<=50. For testing I took an example matrix as:

```
5.0   6.0   7.0
4.0   3.0    8.0
1.0   4.0    2.0
```

I want to read it in same format element-wise using the below code:
But when I compiled it I was getting error:

> At line 15 of file partial_pivot.f90 (unit = 9, file = 'gaussj.inp')
>   Fortran runtime error: End of file.

How this problem can be resolved?

```
program gaussj
implicit none
integer::i,j,n
integer,parameter::nmax=50
real,dimension(nmax,nmax)::A


 open(unit=9,file='gaussj.inp',status='old')
 n = 0
 do i = 1,nmax
   n = n+1

   read(9,*)(A(i,j),j = 1,nmax)


 end do
 close(9)

 write(25,*)((A(i,j),j=1,n),i=1,n)
end program
```

Comment: How big is the matrix in the file? Is it really 50x50 or is it smaller? `nmax` must correspond to the size of the matrix.

Comment: you can simply do `read(9,*)a` (no loops), then `transpose(a)` if needed

Comment: Do yourself a favour and write the dimensions of the array into the first line of the file.  Then you can read the dimensions, allocate the arrays and read them.

Comment: @agentp, that's still going to try to read 2500 elements from a file providing 9.

Comment: oh I misread, I thought he knew the dimension was 50x50 if you do not know *a priori* the number of values on a line it becomes rather cumbersome.. see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/10661901/1004168  ( of course putting the dimension in the file makes life much simpler )

Answer (score 1):

in this case if you want to assume its a square array, (and there is nothing else in the file) you can get the dimension by counting lines..

```
  implicit none
  integer i,n,stat
  real x
  real,allocatable::a(:,:)
  open(20,file='test.dat')
  n=-1
  stat=0
  do while(stat == 0)
     n=n+1
     read(20,*,iostat=stat)x
  enddo
  write(*,*)n
  allocate(a(n,n))
  rewind(20)
  read(20,*)a
  a=transpose(a)
  do i=1,n
     write(*,*)A(i,:)
  enddo
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest way, but working for small matrices in GFortran. This solution is given for rectangular integer matrices, but I guess it can be easily transformed for real matrices as it was in the question. I'm a newbie in coding, so any improvements would be welcome.

```
  Program Example
  Implicit none

  Integer, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A
  Integer :: M, N ! numbers of rows and columns of the input matrix
  Integer :: i

  Character(len=20) :: FMT ! variable format for rows of the matrix
  
  Open(1, FILE='In.txt')  ! file with the input matrix
  Open(2, FILE='Out.txt') ! file for its copy

  Call ReadArray(A, M, N)

  Write(FMT,"( '(',I0,'(I4))') ") N

  Write(2,*) 'Input matrix:'
  Write(2,FMT)(A(i,:),i=1,M)

  Deallocate(A)

  CONTAINS
  
  Subroutine ReadArray(Array, M, N)

        Integer, intent(out), Allocatable, Dimension(:,:) :: Array
        Integer, intent(out) :: M, N ! matrix dimensions
        
        Integer, Allocatable, Dimension(:,:) :: T ! temporary matrix
        Integer, Allocatable, dimension(:) :: RV ! current row vector
        Character*100 s       ! processed line from the input file
        Character :: d = ' '  ! delimiter
        Integer stat, p, q, r           
      
        M = 0  ! number of rows
        N = 0  ! number of columns
        stat=0

        Do while(.TRUE.)
              Read (1, '(a)', iostat=stat) s
              if (stat /= 0) exit
              M = M + 1
        
              If (N==0) then ! determine number of columns
                    p = 1
                    Do
                          q = verify( s(p:), d) ! position of a first non-delimiting symbol
                          if (q == 0) exit
                          r = scan( s(p+q:), d) ! length of the current number                 
                          N = N + 1                  
                          p = p + (q-1) + (r-1) + 1
                    End Do

                    Allocate( RV(1:N) )                        
              End if

              Read(s,*) RV(1:N)                 

              If (M==1) then
                    Allocate (Array(M,N))
              Else
                    Deallocate( Array )
                    Allocate( Array(M,N) )
                    Array(:M-1,:) = T                        
                    Deallocate( T )                   
              End if

              Array(M,:) = RV
              Allocate( T(M,N) )
              T(:,:) = Array                
        End Do

        Deallocate( RV, T )

  End Subroutine ReadArray
  
  End Program Example
```