# Reading unknown size matrix to Fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran

I was wondering how I can read a matrix in a file to Fortran 90 in case dimension of matrix is not known. I know how to get the number of rows for the matrix but have no idea how should know column number to allocate a matrix inside program.
lets say matrix is like this

```
1 2 3 4 50
2 50 2 50 1
21 3 15 515 7
```

I got this for getting number of rows of external file:

```
! GETTING NUMBER OF ROWS
open(unit=11, file=esmfile)
n=0
DO
  READ(11, *, IOSTAT=iostatus) dummy
  IF (iostatus < 0) EXIT
   n = n + 1
END DO
```

Comment: What format is the file in?

Comment: I added a matrix as an example.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:forttan] for all Fortran questions. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314216/reading-data-file-in-fortran-with-known-number-of-lines-but-unknown-number-of-en there is likely to be a closer one somewhere.

Comment: Naturally, if you believe it's a well structured file, you need do the column count determination once only.